# Postgres: get min, max, aggregate values in one select

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions

I am using Postgresql 8.4. I have a table like this:

```
 type | value
------+-------
 1    | 5
 2    | 6
 1    | 4
 3    | 10
```

I want to write one select that will give me the minimum & maximum value, and an aggregate of all the types as `integer[]`. The desired result should be:

```
 min | max | types
-----+-----+-----------
 4   | 10  | {1, 2, 3}
```

To get the min and max, I already have:

```
SELECT MIN(value) min, MAX(value) max FROM table;
```

To get the types in a standalone select, I use:

```
SELECT array_agg(DISTINCT type) types FROM table;
```

How can I combine these into one select (that is not too inefficient)?

Comment: Doesn't `SELECT MIN(value) min, MAX(value) max, array_agg(DISTINCT type) types FROM table;` work for you?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
SELECT array_agg(DISTINCT type) AS types,
       MIN(value) AS min,
       MAX(value) AS max
FROM your_table
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this query:

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT MIN(value),MAX(value) FROM table1)t1,
(SELECT array_agg(DISTINCT type) FROM table1)t2;
```

### [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!11/7d22b/6)