# PostgreSQL: detecting the first/last rows of result set

Tags: postgresql, select, window-functions

Is there any way to embed a flag in a select that indicates that it is the first or the last row of a result set? I'm thinking something to the effect of:

```
> SELECT is_first_row() AS f, is_last_row() AS l FROM blah;
  f  |  l
-----------
  t  |  f
  f  |  f
  f  |  f
  f  |  f
  f  |  t
```

The answer might be in [window functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/functions-window.html) but I've only just learned about them, and I question their efficiency.

```
SELECT first_value(unique_column) OVER () = unique_column, last_value(unique_column) OVER () = unique_column, * FROM blah;
```

seems to do what I want. Unfortunately, I don't even fully understand that syntax, but since `unique_column` is unique and `NOT NULL` it should deliver unambiguous results. But if it does sorting, then the cure might be worse than the disease. (Actually, in my tests, `unique_column` is *not* sorted, so that's something.)

`EXPLAIN ANALYZE` doesn't indicate there's an efficiency problem, but when has it ever told me what I needed to know?

And I might need to use this in an aggregate function, but I've just been told window functions aren't allowed there.

Edit:
Actually, I just added `ORDER BY unique_column` to the above query and the rows identified as first and last were thrown into the middle of the result set. It's as if `first_value()`/`last_value()` really means "the first/last value I picked up before I began sorting." I don't think I can safely do this optimally. Not unless a much better understanding of the use of the `OVER` keyword is to be had.

I'm running PostgreSQL 9.6 in a Debian 9.5 environment.

This isn't a duplicate, because I'm trying to get the first row and last row of the result set to identify themselves, while [Postgres: get min, max, aggregate values in one select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22319408/postgres-get-min-max-aggregate-values-in-one-select) is just going for the minimum and maximum values for a column in a result set.

Comment: What is the purpose of knowing first and last record? What do you want to do it further with it? And yes window function is the best solution for such problems. if you need to aggregate just use the result of your first query as a table in your aggregation query and then it works without problem

Comment: The result set will be sent off to another system asynchronously that will want to know which part of the result set it's looking at. It would be difficult to apply these notations after the result set is produced

Comment: Please define `result set` (maybe add some data + intended results to your question?)

Comment: There is no such thing as the "first" or "last" row in a relational database. Rows in a table are not sorted in any way. So unless you specify a sort definition you can't tell what the "first" row is.

Comment: You have an **empty** window definition : `OVER ()`, which means: *anything goes!*. Compare that to the window definitions in my answer, which **do** impose an order.

Comment: @Opux, to be honest, I think that you overcomplicated things a lot. If you don't order records then first and last is totally random. More important when it goes to another system it can be read in completely different order then in your statement. You will have just 2 records flagged as first last from over few hundred, thousands or millions. Usefulness is close to zero or I miss something very important and don't understand why you want to do it that way.

Comment: @GrzegorzGrabek Because sometimes it's necessary to know when the receiving system is looking at the beginning of a result set and sometimes it is necessary to know if the end of the result set has been reached. Now this is already being done in C++, where the flags and other routines detect and predict the first record being retrieved and the last (no sorting necessary), but we're trying to move routines like this into SQL

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Postgres: get min, max, aggregate values in one select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22319408/postgres-get-min-max-aggregate-values-in-one-select)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `lead()` and `lag()` window functions (over the appropiate window) and compare them to NULL:

---

--     \i tmp.sql

```
CREATE TABLE ztable
( id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
  , starttime TIMESTAMP
);

INSERT INTO ztable (starttime) VALUES ( now() - INTERVAL '1 minute');
INSERT INTO ztable (starttime) VALUES ( now() - INTERVAL '2 minute');
INSERT INTO ztable (starttime) VALUES ( now() - INTERVAL '3 minute');
INSERT INTO ztable (starttime) VALUES ( now() - INTERVAL '4 minute');
INSERT INTO ztable (starttime) VALUES ( now() - INTERVAL '5 minute');
INSERT INTO ztable (starttime) VALUES ( now() - INTERVAL '6 minute');

SELECT id, starttime
        , ( lead(id) OVER www IS NULL) AS is_first
        , ( lag(id) OVER www IS NULL) AS is_last
FROM ztable
WINDOW www AS (ORDER BY id )
ORDER BY id
        ;


SELECT id, starttime
        , ( lead(id) OVER www IS NULL) AS is_first
        , ( lag(id) OVER www IS NULL) AS is_last
FROM ztable
WINDOW www AS (ORDER BY starttime )
ORDER BY id
        ;

SELECT id, starttime
        , ( lead(id) OVER www IS NULL) AS is_first
        , ( lag(id) OVER www IS NULL) AS is_last
FROM ztable
WINDOW www AS (ORDER BY starttime )
ORDER BY random()
        ;
```

---

Result:

---

```
INSERT 0 1
INSERT 0 1
INSERT 0 1
INSERT 0 1
INSERT 0 1
INSERT 0 1
 id |         starttime          | is_first | is_last 
----+----------------------------+----------+---------
  1 | 2018-08-31 18:38:45.567393 | f        | t
  2 | 2018-08-31 18:37:45.575586 | f        | f
  3 | 2018-08-31 18:36:45.587436 | f        | f
  4 | 2018-08-31 18:35:45.592316 | f        | f
  5 | 2018-08-31 18:34:45.600619 | f        | f
  6 | 2018-08-31 18:33:45.60907  | t        | f
(6 rows)

 id |         starttime          | is_first | is_last 
----+----------------------------+----------+---------
  1 | 2018-08-31 18:38:45.567393 | t        | f
  2 | 2018-08-31 18:37:45.575586 | f        | f
  3 | 2018-08-31 18:36:45.587436 | f        | f
  4 | 2018-08-31 18:35:45.592316 | f        | f
  5 | 2018-08-31 18:34:45.600619 | f        | f
  6 | 2018-08-31 18:33:45.60907  | f        | t
(6 rows)

 id |         starttime          | is_first | is_last 
----+----------------------------+----------+---------
  2 | 2018-08-31 18:37:45.575586 | f        | f
  4 | 2018-08-31 18:35:45.592316 | f        | f
  6 | 2018-08-31 18:33:45.60907  | f        | t
  5 | 2018-08-31 18:34:45.600619 | f        | f
  1 | 2018-08-31 18:38:45.567393 | t        | f
  3 | 2018-08-31 18:36:45.587436 | f        | f
(6 rows)
```

---

[updated: added a randomly sorted case]

Comment: What's that first `SELECT` supposed to be? The data seems wrong. It also seems I'd still need to sort. I tried removing the `ORDER BY`s from it, and the data was also wrong.

Comment: I added an extra query to illustrate that the result does not depend on the sorting order.

Comment: My expectation is that the first record will be called the first and the last will be called the last. The 1st query is fine for Jesus (Matt 20:16). But the 2nd gives correct results, but sorts

Comment: The decision first/last is made based on the **window definition**, the final order of the results is unrelated. [ and: apart from the ordering, the results for query #2 and #3 are identical.

Comment: I just edited my question w/a new roadblock. Maybe it makes it clearer what I'm trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1):

It is simple using window functions with particular [frames](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-WINDOW-FUNCTIONS):

```
with t(x, y) as (select generate_series(1,5), random()) 
select *,
  count(*) over (rows between unbounded preceding and current row),
  count(*) over (rows between current row and unbounded following)
from t;
┌───┬───────────────────┬───────┬───────┐
│ x │         y         │ count │ count │
├───┼───────────────────┼───────┼───────┤
│ 1 │ 0.543995119165629 │     1 │     5 │
│ 2 │ 0.886343683116138 │     2 │     4 │
│ 3 │ 0.124682310037315 │     3 │     3 │
│ 4 │ 0.668972567655146 │     4 │     2 │
│ 5 │ 0.266671542543918 │     5 │     1 │
└───┴───────────────────┴───────┴───────┘
```

As you can see `count(*) over (rows between unbounded preceding and current row)` returns rows count from the data set beginning to current row and `count(*) over (rows between current row and unbounded following)` returns rows count from the current to data set end. `1` indicates the first/last rows.

It works until you ordering your data set by `order by`. In this case you need to duplicate it in the frames definitions:

```
with t(x, y) as (select generate_series(1,5), random()) 
select *,
  count(*) over (order by y rows between unbounded preceding and current row),
  count(*) over (order by y rows between current row and unbounded following)
from t order by y;
┌───┬───────────────────┬───────┬───────┐
│ x │         y         │ count │ count │
├───┼───────────────────┼───────┼───────┤
│ 1 │ 0.125781774986535 │     1 │     5 │
│ 4 │  0.25046408502385 │     2 │     4 │
│ 5 │ 0.538880597334355 │     3 │     3 │
│ 3 │ 0.802807193249464 │     4 │     2 │
│ 2 │ 0.869908029679209 │     5 │     1 │
└───┴───────────────────┴───────┴───────┘
```

PS: As mentioned by a_horse_with_no_name in the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52118140/postgresql-detecting-the-first-last-rows-of-result-set#comment91190333_52118463):

> there is no such thing as the "first" or "last" row without sorting.

Comment: That seems to work, too. A bit wordy though. Was I just lucky that `first_value(unique_column) OVER () = unique_column` worked for me and it might not work somewhere down the line? I found that if I sorted, then I was able to get it to work by putting my main query in a subquery, then put the `first_value()` stuff in the superquery.

Comment: @Opux Here is great article with detailed explanation how window functions works: https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/window-functions-in-sql/

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
SELECT columns 
FROM mytable 
Join conditions
WHERE conditions ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1

UNION ALL 

SELECT columns
FROM mytable 
Join conditions
WHERE conditions ORDER BY date ASC LIMIT 1
```

SELECT just cut half of the processing time. You can go for indexing also.

Comment: Yeah, but, therein lies the sorting, which is the kind of thing I wanted to avoid, if possible. AFAIK, window functions don't require sorting

Comment: Refer, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1485391/how-to-get-first-and-last-record-from-a-sql-query

Comment: @Opux: there is no such thing as the "first" or "last" row without sorting. And window functions - if you use them correctly - will require sorting as well

Answer (score 0):

In fact, Window Functions are a great approach and for that requirement of yours, they are awesome.

Regarding efficiency, window functions work over the data set already at hand. Which means the DBMS will just add extra processing to infer first/last values.

Just one thing I'd like to suggest: I like to put an `ORDER BY` criteria inside the `OVER` clause, just to ensure the data set order is the same between multiple executions, thus returning the same values to you.

Comment: It looks like you are right about the sorting. I just edited my question w/a new development. If I need to sort, then I don't think this thing is worth doing. My next endeavour is to better understand `OVER`, in case that offers a solution.