# PostgreSQL: what's wrong with first_value(unique_column) OVER ()?

Tags: postgresql, window-functions

Pursuant to [PostgreSQL: detecting the first/last rows of result set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52118140/postgresql-detecting-the-first-last-rows-of-result-set), I've been given reason to suspect that such a clause is dangerous or otherwise inappropriate, and want to understand that better. Take:

```
SELECT last_value(unique_column) OVER (), * FROM mytable;
```

`unique_column` is unique and not null. So what's wrong with using `OVER ()` in this way? Is it dangerous/unreliable? Suboptimal? From what I can tell, this should return the value from the last row in the result set—at least, it has when I've tried it. I've been told that "last" doesn't make sense without sorting, but clearly there is a last row that is returned. I've also been told that `OVER ()` means "anything goes", which suggests that the results are unreliable, but so far, every time I've run that kind of query, I've been consistently given the value from the end of the result set.

Now I *have* found a problem if I use `ORDER BY`:

```
SELECT last_value(unique_column) OVER (), * FROM mytable ORDER BY something_else;
```

But, my solution to that is to subquery:

```
SELECT last_value(unique_column) OVER (), * FROM (SELECT * FROM mytable ORDER BY something_else) sub;
```

It's as if `OVER ()` means the analytic functions (like `first_value()` and `last_value()`) operate according to the order in which the engine happens the read the table/subquery. And, from what I can tell, you have enough control over the order in which the engine happens to read the table/subquery (without having to do unnecessary sorting).

I'm running PostgreSQL 9.6 in a Debian 9.5 environment.

Comment: You've merely gotten lucky. Your data is NEVER guaranteed to be pulled from the disk in the same order every time. This isn't just "engine pulling from table or subquery" This is literally your postgres instance pulling from data blocks on the drive. You are playing with fire if you think through your entire database stack that it will remain consistent over the long term. It's also good practice to be explicit in your SQL. You know the order you desire, your database doesn't. Tell it.

Comment: @JNevill Thing is, I don't mind if the order of the result set changes. I just want `last_value()` to return the last value *of that result set*

Comment: If you don't care about order, you could just as well use the `first_value()`

Comment: Or likewise, if you don't care just `select myfield from mytable limit 1` we're really talking about negligible performance when grabbing just one record.

Comment: I want to grab multiple records

Comment: @Opux Do you try to implement some sort of paging? Getting last value for unique column(probably PK) indicate that.

Comment: @LukaszSzozda No, I don't know what that is, in this context

Comment: Awesome @Opux If you don't care about order, then you are golden. If you truly want the last item of the result set, that makes 100% perfect sense. I can't imagine a scenario where that would make sense, but it's logically consistent and does what you want it to do  :) Window Functions operate on the result set after it's been retrieved (it's the last step in processing), so this will work like you want it to.

Comment: @JNevill As I tried to explain in the link, I need those analytic functions to get the first and last records in the result set to identify themselves, so the expression I use is closer to `last_value(unique_column) OVER () = unique_column last_row_in_result_set`. This is something we used to take care of in C++ (it's easy: just mark it at the beginning and end of the loop that retrieves the rows) but we are trying to move features like this from C++ to SQL. So until I see why a row in the middle of the result set could be flagged as the last, I'm going to go w/that. Thanks.

Comment: I'm surprised there doesn't exist a feature already in whatever C++  library deals with the returned result set where you could just do `if resultset.eof`. I don't know C++, so perhaps that doesn't exist. I think there is good reason to keep it in C++ though if you are always looping through your returned result sets. If that's the case, c++ would be cheaper then having the database perform that condition on each record before sending it across the wire. Perhaps it's a wash though.

Answer (score 0):

You should provide `ORDER BY` inside `OVER` clause:

```
SELECT *,
 last_value(unique_column) 
 OVER (ORDER BY sth_else ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING)
FROM mytable
```

Comment: Sorting is expensive. What are the consequences of not doing it?

Comment: @Opux `OVER()` without ORDER BY have a little sense for `ROW_NUMBER/RANK/LAST_VALUE/FIRST_VALUE`

Comment: But what could happen? Could there ever be a time when `last_value()` returns a value that is not the last value in that result set? And what could cause that? A race condition? Does locking not prevent that sort of thing from changing mid-query?

Comment: @Opux Let me put it another way. Without explicit ORDER BY order is never guaranteed. If you don't care about order just take any value. You should play with parallel execution and check if you get consistent results between executions.

Answer (score 0):

I should point out that in the last few months, this solution has worked out rather well, and I've not been shown an alternative, so I'm going to continue using it. However, I should point out that it is finicky and can fail if you make certain changes and do not take the analytics into consideration. (No doubt, I'm misusing the feature and it was *not* developed for this purpose). So I'll use this space to record the gotchas as I find them.

1. If you order your results, you've got a problem, but I've already explained that in the question.
2. I tried to use it in an outer join. Since this caused fields in the result set to be null (even though they are taken from fields in a table that cannot be null) this caused `OVER()` to return NULL. I have a few ideas about how to get around this, but they would make the query *very* ugly and possibly very inefficient.